# How to catch python sys.exit(0) in .net core process?

Tags: python, .net, process

I want to run a python script using .net core process. The python code is as follows.
In this python script, there will be sys.exit(0) I want to catch this in the .net core code mentions below the python scritp.

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint

def main() -> None:

    vars = {'customer_name': sys.argv[1],
            'department_name': sys.argv[2],
            'project_name': sys.argv[3]}
    pprint(vars)

    #raise Exception("This is an exception")
    sys.exit(1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to check if the sys.exit(0) is zero or not

```
            try
            {
                string ConfigurationSectionName = "PythonEnv";
                ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
                start.FileName = this.configurationService.ServiceConfiguration<string>("PythonPath", ConfigurationSectionName);
                start.Arguments = this.configurationService.ServiceConfiguration<string>("LaunchScript", ConfigurationSectionName) + " " +
                                    model.CustomerName + " " +
                                    model.DepartmentName + " ";
                start.WorkingDirectory = this.configurationService.ServiceConfiguration<string>("WorkingDir", ConfigurationSectionName);
                start.UseShellExecute = false;// Do not use OS shell
                start.CreateNoWindow = true; // We don't need new window
                start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;// Any output, generated by application will be redirected back
                start.RedirectStandardError = true; // Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)
                using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
                {

                    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                    {

                        string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Here are the exceptions from our Python script
                        string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Here is the result of StdOut(for example: print "test")
                    }
               }
            } catch(Exeception ex) {}
```

Above is the .net core code. How can I catch the exit code?

Comment: If you just want the process' exit code, perhaps you can use [Process.ExitCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode?view=netframework-4.8). But if you're asking "how do I distinguish between a Python program that ended normally, vs a Python program that ended by calling `sys.exit(0)`? They have identical exit codes", then I'm not sure there's an easy solution.

Comment: Hi @Kevin I want to know if the python exited with 0 or some other exit code. Not the process.ExitCode()

Comment: It seems like  Process.ExitCode is not equal to the sys.exit(0)